# How to set CURLOPT_PROXY in Guzzle right way?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I am trying to set CURLOPT_PROXY but it doesn't work. Curl is enabled. If I do this by "raw" curl request - everything works.. So? What could be the solution?

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res = $client->get('http://www.ipmango.com/api/myip', [
    'config' => [
        'curl' => [
            'CURLOPT_PROXY' => '194.135.220.18:8081',
        ],
    ]
]);

echo $res->getBody(); // displays my ip addess, not that what I set.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I spent numerous hours finding out myself that you will also need to set the option `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` to `1`. So something like:

```
<?php
$res = $client->get('http://www.ipmango.com/api/myip', [
'config' => [
    'curl' => [
        'CURLOPT_PROXY' => '194.135.220.18:8081',
        'CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL' => 1,
    ]
   ]
]);
```

Comment: In guzzle v3, instead of  'CURLOPT_PROXY' string, the constant CURLOPT_PROXY should be used

Answer (score 4):

GuzzleHttp Client automatically detects if environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are set.

(see lines 165-175 of \path\to\project\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php)

So set both `HTTP_PROXY=http://ip:port` and `HTTPS_PROXY=https://ip:port` as system environment variables. Now restart your command line, and rerun php artisan serve

You may be able to configure authentication for your proxy in the environment variable as well, if it's required

Comment: Make sure this variable cannot be modified by clients using the Proxy: header. This is known as the HTTPoxy vulnerability (https://httpoxy.org) and the behaviour you described makes it vulnerable.

Comment: Thanks for this tip

Answer (score 1):

Guzzle docs give info about setting proxy for a single request

```
$client->request('GET', '/', ['proxy' => 'tcp://localhost:8125']);
```

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#proxy

But you can set it to all requests when initializing client

```
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://doma.in/',
        'timeout' => 10.0,
        'cookie' => true,
        'proxy' => 'tcp://12.34.56.78:3128',
    ]);
```